# Phone camera connector types

Tags: connector, camera

I have two phone cameras, rear and front, but I don't know which type of connectors are these?
[image]

Comment: That is an problem, you can find different images saying that it is the same connector, MIPI CSI. So I was thinking that someone here has right info. I've tried google before asking question.

Comment: Do you know from which phone they are?

Comment: Yes, Chinese JiaYu S3. I'm generally interested if more than 2 cameras can be connected to the android phone/tablet motherboard. So I've started searching about cameras, and then I found a lot of differences in specifications.

Comment: The interface will be standard (MIPI CSI), but I would expect every phone manufacturer to have it's own connector. Whatever is cheap  and just reliable enough. They don't care if it is standard or proprietary.

Comment: @oldfart The interface doesn't have be MIPI CSI which is quite complex, and could very well be parallel, especially given the small size of the sensor.

Answer (score 2):

The one on the left looks a lot like a 30 pins Panasonic A4S header for which you would need the corresponding [AXE530127](https://octopart.com/search?q=AXE530127) socket. Here is the [product page](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e/control/connector/base-fpc/a4s/index.jsp) for this family of connectors.

However, the connector alone won't be of much help to you, without the pinout information that the sensor manufacturers have a tendency to keep under NDA.

Comment: I think most phone cameras are running MIPI CSI-2 or CSI-3, with C-PHY or D-PHY physical layers. Both have `SCL` and `SDA` lines. D-PHY has `+` and `-` lines for clock and N data channels. C-PHY has no clock and 3 lines per data channel. I think in most cases one could figure it out

Answer (score 1):

The one on the left might be a JAE WP7-series connector. Even though there's an indentation, this is a "plug"-type connector, and you'll want a "receptacle"-type connector to mate with it.

Another gotcha is that although one can count 30 pins, the outer 4 pins are just mechanical tie-downs, so this is actually a 26-pin connector.

You can buy this connector on [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jae-electronics/WP7A-S026VA1-R8000/670-3047-1-ND/8557415) or [Mouser](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/JAE-Electronics/WP7A-S026VA1-R8000).

This may be a MIPI D-PHY with `SCL`, `SDA`, `CLOCK+`, `CLOCK-` and 11 data channels, each with a `DATA+` and `DATA-`.
It might also be a MIPI C-PHY with `SCL`, `SDA`, and 8 data channels, each with `DATA_A`, `DATA_B` and `DATA_C` lines.